# how to save attribute of view that changed programmatically

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I create application that user can drag and drop view anywhere in layout. everything works fine but my question is how can I save position of view that dropped somewhere. because when I close application and come back , views back to first place . one solution is save position in preferences but I want better solution . thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say closed, do you mean the app has been destroyed? If so, you have many options as to how to persist data between sessions, [As documented in the android guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).  Since all you want to do is save the positions, SharedPreferences **are** your best choice since it is primitive data.